# dates under post titles -- also showing up under Nav

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve

I added a filter in `functions.php` in order to have the dates show up under my titles on each Post on my homepage. Random dates are now also showing up in the Nav. Can someone help me make those go away? I'm happy they show on the posts now, so I did something right! But the dates in the Nav have got to go!

I'm developing the site here: internalcompass.us/castle

and I used this code in the child theme twentytwelve in the functions.php to add the dates:

```
<?php
function add_dates_to_title_wpse106605($title, $id) {
if (is_home()){
    $time = get_the_time( $d = 'l, F j, Y', $post = $id );
    return $title . '<br><small class="time">' . $time . '</small>';
} else {
    return $title;
}
}

add_filter('the_title', 'add_dates_to_title_wpse106605', 10, 2);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional check for [`in_the_loop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop) to only affect titles being output within the main query's loop:

```
function add_dates_to_title_wpse106605($title, $id) {
    if ( is_home() && in_the_loop() ){ // <-- added in_the_loop()
        $time = get_the_time( $d = 'l, F j, Y', $post = $id );
        return $title . '<br><small class="time">' . $time . '</small>';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'add_dates_to_title_wpse106605', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, @milo. That actually results in no dates displaying at all. That is the code I was given initially, and I took out the in the loop part bc as I said, no dates show up at all on the posts or in the Nav if that code is included. That's possibly because I have multiple loops -- not sure. Any ideas??

Comment: `in_the_loop()` checks if the main query is being output, so I'll guess you have edited the template and aren't outputting the main loop for some reason. if you want to add the filter to a specific loop, you can move the `add_filter` call to immediately before that specific loop, then [`remove_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) immediately after.

Comment: that doesn't work, although it sounded perfect.

Comment: this is my index.php so you can see the way i'm creating loops if that helps http://pastebin.com/2SvEgEwb

Comment: your add_filter and remove_filter calls are incomplete, you need the entire line with what you're adding the filter to, and the linked function- `add_filter('the_title', 'add_dates_to_title_wpse106605', 10, 2);`, then remove the original add_filter line from your functions.php file so it isn't still applied to all loops